# onclick menu not triggering

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, triggers, onclick

I've ran across some trouble in my coding. Can't seem to figure out what is making my menu act up. I have the [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/VLkT7/) for anyone who wants to take a look.

There is a "Home", "About", and "Sticky" selections on the menu.

-"Home" is just a link.

-"About" menu works fine when clicked on, it drops the menu. When user clicks anywhere on document, drop hides. clicking on it drops and hides the menu as well.

-"Sticky" is where the problem occurs, it should work and function the same as the "About" menu drop. But when clicked on, the drop doesn't happen at all.

Can anyone point out what the problem is?
What's preventing it from triggering?

**Here is the code I am using -

```
$(document).ready( function(){
$('#trigger').click( function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#drop').toggle();
});
$(document).click( function(){
    $('#drop').hide();
}); });
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs can only be used once. Use classes instead, as in `$('.drop',this).toggle();`

[See my working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VLkT7/2/)

Comment: Thank you. That tip helped, however that solution leaves any drop down menu open when user clicks on another menu item.